# What to do with DTOs on the Client side of a WCF Service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mapping, dto

I have a WCF Service which maps EF Entities to DTOs to send the data to a WPF Client application, when the WPF Client updates the service reference it generates all of the DTOs (as partial classes) defined at the Service.

My question is: on the WPFClient side should I directly take these DTOs as Models and extend them using partial classes to add extra fields, methods to fetch the data, etc. Or should I create a new class and map again from the generated DTOs to the new class?

Comment: I'm new at StackOverflow and I've post a few questios and almost all of them seems to be wrong asked, put on hold as "too broad", and this one put on hold as "primaly opinion-based" what does this means? I try to make questions simples, not making them too long, should I explain in detail no mather the size of the question, making it more objective? Sorry for this inconvenients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider creating new objects, treat your DTOs simply as "transport" objects. You don't want to risk ending up with functionality, if any, business logic in your DTOs.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time, so you're saying i need to map from EF Entity to DTO and then on the client from DTO to a class that would be my Model?

Comment: That would be my approach, if using DTO's, leave them as dumb storage containers for transport. Only exception could be data validation as you put data into the DTO. Keep your DTO's simple would be my theme.

Comment: OK thank you very much